# Как сделать отображение мобильной версии сайта?

Tags: html, css

Есть адаптивный сайт, с минимальной шириной контейнера 375px.
Вьюпорт указан следующий:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Проблема в том, что на теефонах с разрешением меньше 375px появляется горизонтальная полоса прокрутки. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при размерахэкрана менее 375px (например 320px), содержимое масштабировалось и полностью помещалось в экран, без горизонтальной полосы прокрутки?

Comment: можно. добавьте в стили  медиа-запрос для max-width:375px и положите в него стиля для узких экранов. (обстильте элементы контента, чтобы ни один из них не превышал ширины экрана, иначе разопрет содержимое, невзирая на ограничения).

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо блоку который оборачивает ваш контент задать значение стилей `position:relative; max-width:100vw; width:100%; overflow:hidden;` это поможет скрыть вылазящие за контент элементы, обычно так происходит если на странице имеються объекты с фиксироваными размерами (примерет `<img>` `<video>`)